# PSSession and Get-Hotfix

Tags: powershell

I am trying to remotely get all the patches on our servers so we know what has what. Below is the script I wrote to achieve this. However, when I execute the script I only get the patches for the local machine that is running the script. What am I doing wrong?

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties operatingsystem;
$filter = "Windows Server*"

foreach($computer in $computers)
{
     if($computer.OperatingSystem -like $filter)
     {
         $name = $computer.Name.ToString();
         write-host "Working on computer: "$name
         New-PSSession -ComputerName $name;
         Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $name | Get-HotFix | Export-Csv "c:\new\$name patches.csv";
        Exit-PSSession;
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked c:\new on any of these computers? I suspect your CSV's from your PSSessions are on the remote machines, not your own.

Comment: Yes, it's not posting it one the computers it's looking for, it's putting it on the local machine that the script is running from. However, I did make a UNC path with the everyone permission and it comes up with this: 
`Access to the path '\\server name\d$\Patches\sample.csv' is denied.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Export-Csv], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand`

Comment: Have you tried just using WMI? Get-WMIObject Win32_QuickFixEngineering -ComputerName $name.

Comment: @EBGreen - No, I have not. Although, I try to stay away from our WMI queries because some of the systems crash when we do query WMI. I am trying to get a perspective of the network and all of it's windows computers. Get thought though, I like it!

Comment: Just to be clear, Get-Hotfix uses WMI anyway.

Comment: @EBGreen - I did not know that! I just looked up the PS command and sure enough, you're right! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enter-PSSession` is only usable interactively.  For scripting you need to use `Invoke-Command`:

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties operatingsystem;
$filter = "Windows Server*"

foreach($computer in $computers)
{
  if($computer.OperatingSystem -like $filter)
   {
     $name = $computer.Name.ToString();
     write-host "Working on computer: "$name
     Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-HotFix} -ComputerName $name | 
       Export-Csv "c:\new\$name patches.csv"
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfect! I was thinking that I could use pssession to do the job. You're AWESOME and ROCK!

Comment: Or skip the Invoke-Command entirely, `Get-HotFix` has a `ComputerName` parameter. `Get-HotFix -ComputerName $name` should work just fine.